# How to query a large dataframe using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large CSV file and I am importing it as a dataframe using `pandas` in Python. 
Consider that there are three columns: `A,B,C`. I want to extract `C`'s value using `A,B`. I am able to do that using the following statement

```
df[(df.A==a) & (df.B==b)].C
```

But I want to do it repeatedly (~10k-15k times) for different `a` & `b`. It takes forever. So is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hard to give an answer without examples but 1) If possible, do it in a batch, don't do it 10k-15k times 2) Set the index as A and B and sort. It is always faster to access elements on a sorted index.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a job for `groupby()`, but an example of what you'd like to do would bring clarity.

Comment: Col A has dates, Col B has stock_ids & Col C has prices. For a particular date, I need the price for every stock @3novak